# can't make event on loaded elements with .load() function in jquery

Tags: jquery, load

For a project I have to recreate the mechanism of old HTML frames, with a static navigation bar in a div and content in an other div changing asyncronously.

I used jQuery "load" function to load html code from external pages in the content div; but when I try to execute event on them I can't. Why so this? What can I do?

Any help would be strongly apreciated.

Thank you so much in advance for help.

My HTML:

```
<body>

    <nav>
        <a href="#"><span>FIRST</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>SECOND</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>THIRD</span></a>
    </nav>

    <article></article>

</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('nav a').click(function() {
        var link = 'includes/'+clearLink($(this).children().html())+'.html';
        $('<div id="mainframe"></div>').appendTo('article').load(link);
});
```

Now, in the first page I load there are some html element and I can't interact on them, like

```
$('#switch').live('click', function() {

    $('#other-element-loaded-async').hide();
});
```

Comment: This probably isn't your problem, but from the code you've quoted, note that the second time someone clicks a navigation link, you'll have an invalid document, because you'll append a *second* `div` to the "article" element with the `id` "mainframe", and `id` values **must** be unique on the page.

Comment: Separately, the HTML you've quoted is invalid. It starts with `<body>` but ends with `</div>`. There's no `div` to close.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the central problem is that you're ending up with an invalid document which has multiple elements with the same `id` value. In fact, barring code you haven't shown up, you'll have an invalid document the second time someone clicks a navigation link, because this code:

```
$('<div id="mainframe"></div>').appendTo('article').load(link);
```

...*appends* a `div` with the `id` "mainframe" to the `article` element, without removing the previous one. So you'd have two divs with the same ID. If the content you're loading also uses ID values (e.g., "switch" and "other-element-loaded-async"), you'll also end up duplicating those.

You need to ensure that you always have no more than **one** element with a given ID. You could do that by replacing the line above with:

```
$('article').empty().append($('<div id="mainframe"></div>').load(link));
```

[Working example here](http://jsbin.com/elorev) (I also fixed what I suspect was a copy-and-paste error in the quoted HTML)

If you can get rid of that surrounding "mainframe" `div` (putting it in the loaded content instead of the code), you can get a better user experience because we wouldn't have to empty the `article` prior to the new content arriving from the server. The code also gets simpler:

```
$('article').load(link);
```

---

**Original answer**:

You haven't given enough information to really answer your question, but my guess is your code looks like this:

```
$("#target").load(url);
$("#target selector_for_loaded_content").bind("someevent", ...);
```

where it needs to look like this:

```
$("#target").load(url, function() {
    $("#target selector_for_loaded_content").bind("someevent", ...);
});
```

[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) happens *asynchronously*, so in the first code block above, the elements don't exist yet and so they don't get hooked up. In the second code block, we use the `load` function's callback so that we wait to hook them up until they have been loaded.

Another approach, depending on what events you're using and what else you're doing with the elements once they're loaded, would be to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate):

```
$("#target").load(url);
$("#target").delegate("selector_for_loaded_content", "someevent", ...);
```

`delegate` hooks the event on the target, but then looks to see if it bubbled up to that target through something matching the selector, and if so fires the event function (mostly) as if the event had been hooked on the element. This is very handy for dynamic pages where you're creating/removing lots of elements.

If you're using jQuery 1.7 or later, while `delegate` is still there, you can also use the new [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) which the jQuery team say is the way forward for all event hookup:

```
$("#target").on("someevent", "selector_for_loaded_content", ...);
```

Note that the order of arguments is different between `delegate` and `on`.

Comment: Thanks T.J., I've edit my post with some code, I hope it was helpful.

Comment: @bobighorus: If what you load really has an element with the `id` value "switch", and nothing else eats the `click` event before it reaches the document (which is where `live` hooks it), what you're doing should work other than the issue I've mentioned in a comment on the question. So I'd double-check that "switch" is really an `id`, and that nothing else in the hierarchy between that element and the document is eating the click.